# Dúvida referente a Count em comando SQL

Tags: sql, count

Preciso contar a quantidade de suprimentos disponíveis no estoque de acordo com o seu `codigoSuprimento`, para isso criei o seguinte comando sql:

```
select count(codigosuprimento) quantidade, codigosuprimento from public.estoque where usado = '0' group by codigosuprimento order by codigosuprimento
```

Porém como eu coloquei que eu gostaria que ele selecionasse apenas os que ainda possuem pelo menos um disponível (`usado = '0'`) quando o suprimento existe no estoque mas não tem nenhum disponível ele não me retorna nada, é possível que ele me retorne `0` caso não haja nenhum disponível no estoque naquele momento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Que tal agrupar usando `sum()` com um somatório condicional:

```
SELECT
    sum( CASE WHEN usado = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) quantidade,
    codigosuprimento
FROM
    public.estoque
GROUP BY
    codigosuprimento
ORDER BY
    codigosuprimento;
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente para o que eu precisava, muito obrigado +1

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se você teria muito impacto na performance mas poderia fazer dois *selects* e usar *union*:

```
SELECT COUNT(codigosuprimento) quantidade, codigosuprimento 
FROM public.estoque 
WHERE usado = '0' 
GROUP BY codigosuprimento 
ORDER BY codigosuprimento

UNION

SELECT distinct 0 as quantidade, codigosuprimento 
FROM public.estoque 
WHERE usado <> '0'
```